# Sequential inference of a Gaussian process with large data

Tags: gaussian-process

In Gelman's [Bayesian Data Analysis 3](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Eave/BDA3.pdf), on page 504, in the chapter on Gaussian processes, it says:

> In the univariate case the computation can be made in time O(n) using
> sequential inference, and computation is no problem even for n greater
> than million.

What method(s) are the writer referring to here?

I tried browsing trough the references in the Bibliographic note, but couldn't get far.